# Why is the tensorflow 'accuracy' value always 0 despite loss decaying and evaluation results being reasonable

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm building a model to perform a linear regression of the equation `y=mx+c`. I generated a csv file of 1999 samples and a model where I can change the normalization (on / off), number of layers, number of nodes and number of epochs. I expected to be able to use the loss / accuracy of the training and evaluation to guide the selection of these variable in situations where I do not know the answer in advance but am confused by my results so far as summarized below:

```
Normalization   Layers  Nodes   Epochs  Start Loss  End Loss    Accuracy

TRUE               1    200       5     0.6022      0.4348      0

TRUE               1    200      50     0.5963      0.4347      0

TRUE              10    200       5     0.5249      0.4525      0

TRUE              10    200      50     0.5157      0.4418      0

TRUE              10    500       5     0.5816      0.4825      0

TRUE              10    500      50     0.5591      0.4422      0

FALSE              1    200       5   996.2897      1.8313      0

FALSE              1    200      50  1063.1994      1.7264      0

FALSE             10    200       5   421.1371     40.6160      0

FALSE             10    200      50   293.6943     46.2854      0

FALSE             10    500       5   382.2659    297.2881      0

FALSE             10    500      50   412.2182     79.7649      0
```

The compile parameters I am using are

`compile optimizer:adam loss:mean_absolute_error metrics:['accuracy'] loss_weights:[1.0]`

an example model summary is

```
Model: "LRmodel"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

LR-input (InputLayer)        [(None, 1)]                 0 
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 200)               400

_________________________________________________________________
ML-LinearRegression (Dense)  (None, 1)                 201


Total params: 601

Trainable params: 601

Non-trainable params: 0
```

example fitting result is

```
1600/1600 - 1s - loss: 1063.1994 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 90.2848 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 2/5

1600/1600 - 0s - loss: 137.8654 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.1525 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 3/5

1600/1600 - 0s - loss: 4.4340 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 3.4557 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 4/5

1600/1600 - 0s - loss: 1.7573 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 3.1190 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 5/5

1600/1600 - 0s - loss: 1.7264 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 3.2794 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Additionally there are 2 issues I do not understand

1. Sometimes the fitting has a high loss that never changes and the model is unable to calculate results. When this happens I run the training (sometimes several times) again and eventually get the results described above with no changes to data or code.
2. Normalization produces a model that is less accurate that when I do not normalize the model.

Comment: We have commented this many times in SO, accuracy is a metric only for classification problems, not for regression, so it makes no sense to use it in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do not show your model. However if you are doing linear regression you should not use accuracy as a metric. Accuracy is used when you are doing classification such as trying to classify if an image is a dog or a cat. You should use a loss function in model.compile that is appropriate for liner regression like `tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError`. Documentation for regression losses is [here.](https://keras.io/api/losses/regression_losses/) Documentation for regression metrics is [here.](https://keras.io/api/metrics/regression_metrics/)